# Drawing a line in a 1024-lines mode

Tags: assembly, x86, draw, bios, vesa

I am trying to get a line drawn in video mode 105h using `int 10h`.

When I try:

```
mov cx, 10  ;col
mov dx, 10  ;row
mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel
```

nothing is displayed on screen.

The mode I try is 1024x768.
I understand that I need to create a font file to get text on the screen.
But that won’t be a problem when I get the line or a pixel working.

```
BITS 16
ORG 100h
mov ax, ds
mov es, ax 
;Set video mode
mov ax, 4f02h
mov bx, 105h
int 10h
;Wait for key
xor ax, ax
int 16h
;Restore DOS text mode
mov ax, 0003h
int 10h
;Exit
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
modeInfo    TIMES 256 db 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The video mode 105h is a 1024x768 256-color **VESA** defined video mode.

Although you clearly have read [MagaretBloom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540401/drawing-pixels-in-vesa-graphic-mode/50541923#50541923), not every BIOS will work for these extended video modes!
The BIOS.WritePixel function 0Ch normally only operates on the **LEGACY** video modes. Those are the video modes whose number ranges from 0 to 19.

Your best choices are to setup the 640x480 16-color video mode (number 18), or the 320x200 256-color video mode (number 19).

For the VESA modes, you'll have to write your own output routines...
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590078/how-can-i-write-directly-to-the-screen/4591232#4591232)
I have written lots of code like this and maybe one day I will decide to post about it. Sadly that day has not yet arrived. :-(